# Execute Snakemake rule repeatedly until certain conditions are met

Tags: loops, snakemake, checkpoint

I'd like to use Snakemake for a flow which requires that a certain step be repeatedly performed until certain conditions are met.  It's impossible to determine in advance how many times the step will be needed.  It could be 1 or 6 or any other number.

My gut feeling is this is something Snakemake cannot do because Directed *Acyclic* Graph and all...

I was hoping that a checkpoint might be helpful, though, because it triggers a reevaluation of the DAG, but I just can't understand exactly how it works.

Is a loop in the Snakefile possible?

Thanks!

---

Adding some commentary on what's actually happening in the excellent answer below.  Hopefully it helps others and myself when I inevitably revisit this question.

```
all:  call function all_input to determine rule's input requirements.
all_input:  file "succes.txt" doesn't exist.  do checkpoint keep_trying with i == 1.     
keep_trying:  output "round_1" doesn't exist.  do run section.  random() decides to touch output[0], which is "round_1".

snakemake reevaluates graph after checkpoint is complete

all:  call function all_input to determine rule's input requirements.
all_input:  file "succes.txt" doesn't exist.  do checkpoint keep_trying with i == 2.
keep_trying:   output "round_2" doesn't exist.  do run section.  random() decides to touch output[0], which is "round_2".

snakemake reevaluates graph after checkpoint is complete

all:  call function all_input to determine rule's input requirements.
all_input:  file "succes.txt" doesn't exist.  do checkpoint keep_trying with i == 3.
keep_trying:  output "round_3" doesn't exist.  do run section.  random() decides to touch "succes.txt".

snakemake reevaluates graph after checkpoint is complete

all:  call function all_input to determine rule's input requirements.
all_input:  file "succes.txt" exists.  return "success.txt" to rule all.
all:  input requirement is "success.txt", which is now satisfied.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that you need checkpoints for this! Here is a little example that does what you want:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path


tries = 0
def all_input(wildcards):
    global tries
    if not os.path.exists("succes.txt"):
        tries += 1
        checkpoints.keep_trying.get(i=tries)
    else:
        return "succes.txt"


rule all:
    input:
        all_input


checkpoint keep_trying:
    output:
        "round_{i}"
    run:
        import random
        if random.random() > 0.9:
            Path('succes.txt').touch()
        Path(output[0]).touch()
```

Here we say that `rule all` needs as input what gets returned from the function `all_input`. This function checks whether or not the file `succes.txt` already exists. If it doesn't it will trigger a run of the checkpoint keep trying which might make the `succes.txt` file (10% chance). If `succes.txt` actually exists, then that is the input for `rule all`, and snakemake exits succesfully.